# AMP-HTML Product Color Carousel Collision

Tags: amp-html

I am having an issue creating a Google Amp Page that has two dynamic Carousels on the same page

Each carousel has the following functionality:
When the user selects the color button the image changes to match the color and the buy now button changes to update the link for the chosen color.

All seems to be working well except for one issue. On a fresh reload, when I select the color on either of the two carousel, the buy now button on the other carousel disappears. Choosing any of the colors for the effected carousel restores the missing button and all is well and both buttons remain visible regardless of further interactions

Any thoughts regarding why this is occurring?

```
enter code here
<!-- Product 1 -->
<amp-carousel id="CC50" width="414" height="550" layout="responsive" type="slides" [slide]="product.selectedSlideFor50" class="show  fadeIn">
  <a href="https://www.example.com">
    <amp-img src="image-50w.jpg" alt="Complete Care 5.0 White" width="414" height="550" layout="responsive" class="selected" tabindex="0">
    </amp-img>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.example.com">
    <amp-img src="image-50b.jpg" alt="Complete Care 5.0 Black" width="414" height="550" layout="responsive" tabindex="0">
    </amp-img>
  </a>
</amp-carousel>
<p class="chooseColor">Choose Color</p>
<ul class="colorSelector">
  <li [class]="product.selectedSlideFor50 == 0 ? 'active' : ''" class="active">
    <div on="tap:AMP.setState({product: {selectedSlideFor50 : 0 }})" class="square white" role="button">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li [class]="product.selectedSlideFor50 == 1 ? 'active' : ''">
    <div on="tap:AMP.setState({product: {selectedSlideFor50 : 1 }})" class="square black" role="button">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<a href="https://www.example.com" [class]="product.selectedSlideFor50 == 1 ? 'show' : 'hide'" class="hide">
  <div class="btn">BUY BLACK NOW </div>
</a>
<a href="https://www.example.com" [class]="product.selectedSlideFor50 == 0 ? 'show' : 'hide'" class="show">
  <div class="btn">BUY White NOW</div>
</a>

<!-- Product 2 -->
<amp-carousel id="CC55" width="420" height="570" layout="responsive" type="slides" [slide]="product.selectedSlideFor55" class="show  fadeIn">
  <a href="https://www.example.com">
    <amp-img src="image-55b.jpg" alt="Complete Care 5.5 Black" width="414" height="550" layout="responsive" class="selected" tabindex="0">
    </amp-img>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.example.com">
    <amp-img src="image-55w.jpg" alt="Complete Care 5.0 White" width="414" height="550" layout="responsive" tabindex="0">
    </amp-img>
  </a>
</amp-carousel>
<p class="chooseColor">Choose Color</p>
<ul class="colorSelector">
  <li [class]="product.selectedSlideFor55 == 1 ? 'active' : ''">
    <div on="tap:AMP.setState({product: {selectedSlideFor55 : 1 }})" class="square white" role="button">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li [class]="product.selectedSlideFor55 == 0 ? 'active' : ''" class="active">
    <div on="tap:AMP.setState({product: {selectedSlideFor55 : 0 }})" class="square black" role="button">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<a href="https://www.example.com" [class]="product.selectedSlideFor55 == 0 ? 'show' : 'hide55'" class="show">
  <div class="btn">BUY BLACK NOW </div>
</a>
<a href="https://www.example.com" [class]="product.selectedSlideFor55 == 1 ? 'show' : 'hide55'" class="hide55">
  <div class="btn">BUY White NOW</div>
</a>
```